# issue with cp command when i was copying in /var/www

Tags: sudo, cp

i am not able to copy file in /var/www with
`sudo cp /home/index.html /var/www`

the error is

```
cp:omitting directory '/home/index.html'
```

then i used -r, `sudo cp -r /home/index.html /var/www`, then the error is

```
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory '/var/www/index.html' with directory '/home/index.html'
```

Comment: Is `/home/index.html` a file or folder? I'm not sure, but your error message make it looks like it is a folder, but it should be a regular file.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the error message, `/home/index.html` is a directory (folder), not a file, and `/var/www/index.html` already exists and it is a regular file.

To see if `/home/index.html` is a directory, try:

```
file /home/index.html
```

It will probably say: `/home/index.html: directory`.

If that's the case, you cannot copy a directory over file. Maybe the file you're trying to copy is *inside* the directory `/home/index.html`? Then the command would be something like

```
sudo cp -r /home/index.html/index.html /var/www
```